# MATLAB: Conditionally matrix elements into two separate cell arrays

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, conditional-statements, cells

A matrix has 2 rows and several columns, and the first contains alternating strings of 1's and 0's. I want to use this binary as a decision to copy the information below it into one of two cell arrays. I understand that this can be done through iteration with the use of the IF conditional, or with while loops, but I'm having trouble cleaning it up.

For example, for

```
mat = [ 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ;...
        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ]
```

I would like to output two cell arrays, one for the '1s', and one for the '0s':

```
1 2 3
6 7
5 6 7
```

and:

```
4 5
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Is it crucial to have each sequence in a separate row?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this, I am sure.   One might be using a loop; however, you can also make good use with the built-in find function.  Below is a sample solution based on your example.

For '1s',
Here, we would like to get the indices with '1' from the first row.

```
on_array= mat(2, find(mat(1,:)));
```

> **or as suggested by @H.Muster**
>
> ```
> on_array= mat(2, mat(1,:)==1);
> ```

For '0s',
Here, we would like to get the indices with '0' from the first row.

```
off_array = mat(2, find(mat(1,:)==0));
```

> **or as suggested by @H.Muster**
>
> ```
> off_array= mat(2, mat(1,:)==0);
> ```

For the output format(the one that you want), i am sure you know what to do.   Good luck.

Comment: The use of ´find` is not necessary in this case,  `mat(2, mat(1,:)==0)` is just fine.

Comment: I also propose `logical(mat(1,:))` and `not(mat(1,:)`. I think Matlab likes logical indexing better than `find`.